# Make advanced font settings using JS?

Tags: javascript, substitution, font-family, font-replacement

The "Standard", "Sans-Serif", "Serif", "Monospace" are set to font-names by the browsers and its users with extensions like the "Advanced font setting" which is written in JS. is there a way to change the font-names that it refers to with javascript or its librairies ?

Comment: Extensions are different. They have way more access than normal web pages.

Comment: Maybe using SASS or LESS to change the font-families set by default or by UI ? 
Can someone tell me if ever tried ?

Comment: No way to reset generic font families mapping with JS or browser code ?